# A single sql query to return as multiple tables in a dataset

Tags: c#, sql

I was wondering if i can use a single query in sql server 2005 to return as a dataset in c#, asp.net 2005 into different tables.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = new BusinessLogic.BizLogic().getData(int repID);
for(ds != null)
{
    txtDate.Text = ds.Tables[2].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
}
```

Want to figure out, how to write the store procedure to have multiple tables.A simple example would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You absolutely can, although you may want to consider the overall goal and implications of considering this design.

In your stored procedure you just simply have multiple selects ala..

```
select xxx, yyy from table1
select zzz, nnn from table2
```

Along those lines.

Comment: Thank you, but can it be done with a single select statement? by adding something to the where clause?!! Because i have quite a big stored proc and not sure how many rows it is going to return. I need different tables for distinct dates, if it can help you solve.

Comment: @Ram if filtering your data by dates is what you want then using a DataSet with multiple tables of the same schema is not good practice and somewhat a waste of resources.

Comment: Thank you @Lloyd , can you suggest me any other simple way!??

Comment: @Ram modify your query to return the set of data you are afer, if you want multiple sets then run the query multiple times, this allows you to index your data in a more appropriate manner and write procedures accordingly. For SQl Server 2005 and above look at using ROW_NUMBER() and OVER.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: If i have not asked the question properly, take it this way. I was speaking about tables in the Dataset (c#) and not the tables in the database.

Comment: @Ram I understood what you meant howev er using DataSets large basically duplicate sets of tables with different sets of data grouped and filtered by dates is arguably not a very good practice as you then have to query and retrieve the data that you want from within the DataSet using filters or Table lookups. It would be quicker to query the database for the data you need when you need it.

Comment: That was a perfect explanation. Thank you so much @Lloyd :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes its easy, you can do it via a proc or via inline sql, but like the above poster said, consider the implications.

```
 using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                string sql = "Select * From table1; Select * From table2;";
                using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn))
                {
                    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                    var ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables.Count); // Will show 2 !

                }

            }
```